# "the beginning of waiting" or "the onset of waiting"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Situation : 
There is a girl who can't be together with her boyfriend because he is in army. And thinking of the moment that she has to let him go to army, can she say,

> 1. That was the beginning of waiting for him.
> 2. That was the onset of waiting for him.

Or are there any good expressions for the moment that someone start to wait for the other?

Answer (score 1):

Those are grammatical utterances but not quite natural.  A native speaker, in conversation, is not likely to choose either of those patterns, which use a noun phrase, but instead would treat **waiting** as a *verb* and say something like

> That was when I **started waiting** for him.
>
> That was when I **began waiting** for him.
>
> That was when I **began to wait** for him.

Alternatively, the speaker would use the noun **wait**:

> That was the beginning of my wait for him.
>
> That was when my wait began.

In a story you might read:

> That was when **the waiting** began.

especially if the theme of the story is her waiting for him in a number of ways, sometimes literally, sometimes figuratively, over the course of a long relationship.